# JavaScript toggle div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Basically I am trying to toggle a div. Here is my html:

```
        <div id='top-bar'>   
    </div>
    <div class="toggleButton" >+</div>
```

And my CSS:

```
.toggleButton
{
    left: 50%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 20%;
    z-index: 1;
}
.toggleButton.expanded{
  content: "-";
}
#top-bar
{
    position: absolute;
    background: linear-gradient(black, #F2F2F2);
    width:100%;
    height: 50px;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
}
```

And my JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var $content = $("#top-bar").show();
$(".toggleButton").on("click", function(e) {
    $(this).toggleClass("expanded");
    $content.slideToggle();
});
});
```

And my fiddle here: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KJ3Da/)

When I toggle, the top-bar div did moved up. but the content of toggle button does not change to "-" and it also never shift up. I wonder how to fix this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can check for existence of toggled class and then set its html:

```
if( $(this).hasClass('expanded'))
 $(this).html('+');
else
 $(this).html('-');
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Cj69x/)**

Comment: But the toggleButton does not shift up when the top-bar is hidden. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: @add position: relative; to `toggleButton` and remove absolute position for top bar. check this: http://jsfiddle.net/Cj69x/

Comment: But if I remove the absolute position, the toggleButton will be hide under the top-bar div

Comment: Yeah I checked it. But when I change my position to relative, the "+" sign does not show up and the the margin and padding is not working.

Comment: Do you have any idea?]

Comment: some css is conflicting . need to see it.will take time. am out now.will look into it once back. ok..

Comment: Sure, take your time. Do help me take a look at my fiddle to check what went wrong when you free. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest approach to make it work with the CSS `content` rule is to make it a `:before` or `:after` pseudo-element.

```
.toggleButton:before
{
    left: 50%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 20%;
    z-index: 1;
    content: "+";
}
.toggleButton.expanded:before{
  content: "-";
}
```

See it here: http://jsfiddle.net/KJ3Da/1/

And if you want its position to change based on the topnav item, you need to drop the absolute positioning.  See it here: http://jsfiddle.net/KJ3Da/2/

Comment: But the toggleButton does not shift up when the top-bar is hidden. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: Yup, just updated my answer. It's because of the absolute positioning, I've added a simple fix, though there are many ways to do it.

Comment: But if I drop the position property, the z-index does not work. So the div is somehow hide under other div

Comment: Try the relative position then.

Comment: If I put relative, it still hide under the top-bar div. Do you have any idea?

Comment: Can you make an example of the problem? I see only what you did in the original JSfiddle and that works fine. Sounds like you could fix it by adding margins or padding.

Comment: Do you have any idea to specify the content as image URL?

Comment: The fiddle won't open for some reason and there's no way to use content to show an image, but you can use background-image instead.

Answer (score 0):

Like Shomz said, you should always use the `:before` or `:after` pseudo selector if you are going to use the content property. In order to keep the basic style of toggle button you should set the content property separate from the other properties. Otherwise the base style will only affect `.toggleButton:before` and not `.toggleButton.expanded:before`. So just add this to your CSS.

```
.toggleButton:before {
    content: "+";
}

.toggleButton.expanded:before {
    content: "-";
}
```

And of course remove the `+` from your HTML and the style declaration for `.toggleButton.expanded` from your CSS. Good luck!